# Zookeeper communication protocol

Tags: apache-zookeeper, kafka-consumer-api

I need to debug the data being exchanged between my kafka consumer and zookeeper using tcpdump. I went through the zookeeper documentation but could not find any write up about the zookeeper communication protocol i.e I get the following data dump using wireshark after removing headers. How do I interpret the data part?

```
Frame 1: 78 bytes on wire (624 bits), 78 bytes captured (624 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: 22:00:0a:xx:xx:xx (22:00:xx:xx:xx:xx), Dst: fe:ff:xx:xx:xx:xx (fe:ff:ff:xx:xx:xx)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 10.234.xxx.xxx, Dst: 10.231.xxx.xxx
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 51720 (51720), Dst Port: 2181 (2181), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 12
Data (12 bytes)
    Data: 00000008fffffffe0000000b
    [Length: 12]
```

Comment: "Competitors" claim: «Zookeeper has its own custom Jute RPC protocol, which is totally unique to Zookeeper and limits its supported language bindings» https://etcd.io/docs/v3.4.0/learning/why/
Jute is being reconsidered, I understand. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-102

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sorry, but I'm not aware of any convenient documentation that describes the Apache ZooKeeper wire protocol in any great detail.  Internally, our codebase is using a framework called Jute, which is based on code originally adapted from Apache Hadoop.  The framework allows definition of structured records, generates code based on those definitions, and then provides serialization/deserialization routines called by the rest of the ZooKeeper code.

The Jute record definitions are visible here:

https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/release-3.4.9/src/zookeeper.jute

The Jute framework code for handling these record definitions is visible here:

https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/tree/release-3.4.9/src/java/main/org/apache/jute

I think the only option for a deep understanding of the wire protocol would be to dig into this code.

After digging through a few layers of raw socket handling code (which uses either NIO or Netty depending on configuration), the real work of deserializing the payload happens in `ZooKeeperServer#processPacket(ServerCnxn, ByteBuffer)`:

https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/release-3.4.9/src/java/main/org/apache/zookeeper/server/ZooKeeperServer.java#L941

This is where it deserializes a `RequestHeader`, which is a common header of metadata at the front of all of the protocol's messages.  The definition of `RequestHeader` is shown here:

https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/release-3.4.9/src/zookeeper.jute#L88-L91

We can see it consists of 2 4-byte integer fields: a connection ID followed by the type of the message.  The type values are defined in `ZooDefs` here:

https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/release-3.4.9/src/java/main/org/apache/zookeeper/ZooDefs.java#L28

Knowing all of this, let's go back to your packet capture and try to make sense of it:

```
Data: 00000008fffffffe0000000b

00000008 - payload length
fffffffe - connection ID
0000000b - op code ("ping")
```

At the front of each message (even before the `RequestHeader`), there is the length of the payload.  Here we see a length of 8 bytes.

The next 4 bytes are the connection ID, `fffffffe`.

The final 4 bytes are the op code, `0000000b` (or 11 in decimal).  Reading `ZooDefs`, we can see that this is the "ping" operation.  The "ping" operation is used for periodic heartbeats between client and server.  There is no additional data required in the payload for the "ping" operation, so this is the end of this packet, and there is no additional data after it.  For different operations, there would be additional data in the payload, representing the arguments to the operation.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I went through the documentation but did not understand how is the metadata attached? Where do we specify what type of request is a particular message? Sorry but I was thinking in lines of header deconstruction like TCP packets. The documentation helps though.

Comment: @ankshah , I just edited my answer to provide links to a few more relevant points in the ZooKeeper codebase, and then I used that information to give a detailed walkthrough of the specific packet capture you posted in your question.  I hope this is helpful.